# from_tensor_slices returns an empty object

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to Python and I am using tensorflow to load images and label in a dataset.

```
data_test = pathlib.Path(test_path)

all_test_paths = list(data_test.glob('*/*'))

all_test_paths = [str(path) for path in all_test_paths]

random.shuffle(all_test_paths)

label_names = sorted(item.name for item in data_test.glob('*/') if item.is_dir())
label_to_index = dict((name, index) for index, name in enumerate(label_names))

all_test_labels = [label_to_index[pathlib.Path(path).parent.name]
                    for path in all_test_paths]

all_test_paths=tf.convert_to_tensor(all_test_paths)

test_path_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(all_test_paths)

print(test_path_ds.output_shapes)
```

When I ran this part of the code it returns this:`()`

Comment: Could you tell me what it should be returning instead?

Comment: a dataset of image

Comment: You're creating a dataset from a list of strings. So you won't get images out of this. Read [loading images from directory](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images) here.

Comment: Sorry, a dataset of image path, that's why it's a list of strings. I used Tensorflow tutorials in here [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r1/tutorials/load_data/images.ipynb)